# Linux distribution suited for a clean and easy Drupal 8 install

Tags: 8

I am experiencing a series of issues trying to prepare a server on my professional environment for running Drupal 8. By default, the IT team will install CentOS 6. More precisely, we are running CentOS 6.7.

The issue here is that the default versions of PHP and MySQL on that version of CentOS won't match the minimum required versions for running Drupal 8, which requires us to use repositories. As we are not Linux ninjas, we are facing several problems with the repos. I have two versions of libmysqlclient on the system, but the system will only 'see' the old one which doesn't support the MySQL version required by Drupal. The thing is really getting cumbersome.

So my next approach would be to suggest the IT team to go with the ideal Linux distribution which wouldn't require us to use the repositories, one that can deliver the cleanest install of PHP, Apache, MySQL, phpMyAdmin and Drush.

Based on your experience installing Drupal 8 on Linux servers, what is your preferred setup (Linux distribution), requiring minimum effort from server administrator, to install the appropriate versions of PHP, Apache, MySQL, phpMyAdmin and Drush that will work 'out of the box', discarding the use of custom repos? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but probably should be reworded in some way. Asking the "best" of something is pretty much opinion-based unless you've set some object criteria. It looks like you've defined that criteria (i.e. minimal package configuration for D8), but my guess is you're going to get a wide variety of replies based on everyone's favorite distro or tools.

Comment: Shawn, thank you for your comment. Actually, being broad is what I meant. Really, that is OK for me, I don't need people to be too specific. I have experienced a series of issues to setup the server with CentOS 6.7, possibly because of my lack of Linux skills. But definitely, if I was to pick CentOS 6.7, I would have to choose a repo and navigate some dire waters until I could make it work, and I have already spent some hours on this. My radically different approach now is: what if I ask the community for their experience on setting up environments which are more promptly ready for Drupal 8?

Comment: Shawn, I have reworded part of my question to try to make my request more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, open ended questions are discouraged on DA with the goal being quality knowledge base (at the expense of open discussion).

Comment: I'll leave one parting thought for you. If you're really looking for minimal maintenance, you should consider a PaaS Drupal providers like Acquia & Pantheon. If you need to own your infrastructure then you should consider a Drupal-specific provisioning setup like DrupalVM or Vlad.

Comment: Shawn, thank you. I agree with you and I would go for it if it depended solely on me. In this case, though, I will be working on developing a corporate intranet on Drupal and the setup must be done in our infrastructure.

Comment: Consider docker as a means to contain your setup and isolate it from the host operating system, also with repeatability steps. There is a Drupal 8 docker project too. Have a look around on the web for some further info. Here's something to start with: https://www.drupal.org/node/2538074

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts on the docker project.

Answer (score 1):

Now that is released, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with php 7.0, perfect for drupal 8.

Comment: 4k4, thank you for your comment, I will share this idea with the IT guys and check if we can go with this flavour. If we decide to do so, I will comment again on this post and share it with you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not slagging on you here, but this demonstrates the problem with open-ended, opinion based questions.  Why is Ubuntu 16.04 a better option than CentOS 7 w/ EPEL and IUS?

Comment: No, this demonstrates this is a great channel for this type of question. I came from nothing and I already know I can try Vlad (as per Shawn's comment above), Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or even CentOS 7 w/ EPEL. I can now read more on these distributions and opt for one of them.